# lxd container with openvpn server does not apply iptables nat rule

Tags: 16.04, iptables, openvpn, lxd, nat

I'm trying to setup openvpn on one of my lxd containers to allow access to the container network. The server seem to work and I can access (ping) containers which have a static route pointing to the openvpn server for my external/source network.

I would like to not have to change the routing table of every container and thought I could hide the vpn clients behind the vpn server using NAT.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.144.79.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.144.79.127
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.144.79.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Produces a rule that I believe should achieve that. But `ping` packets from the vpn client still appear to come from the assigned 10.8.0.0/24-adress rather than being masked to 10.144.79.127.

The first rule produces:

```
root@openvpn:~# iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  10.8.0.0/24          10.144.79.0/24       to:10.144.79.127
```

But `tcpdump` on the ping target in 10.144.79.0/24 still looks like:

```
13:56:10.930826 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.144.79.212: ICMP echo request, id 33133, seq 10093, length 64
13:56:10.930855 IP 10.144.79.212 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 33133, seq 10093, length 64
```

Which of course only works if `.212` knows to route `10.8.0.0/24` over `10.144.79.127`.

Forwarding is active:

```
root@openvpn:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
root@openvpn:~# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I setup three virtualbox vm's to verify that I can get NAT working when LXD is not part of the equation, and that works as expected.

Why does the container ignore the POSTROUTING rule?

Comment: Did you allow ip_forwarding on host?

Comment: I believe I would not see the ping packet on the remote container if I didn't. So: yes.

Comment: Not sure as in LXD is just running software containers, can you just type `sudo sysctl -p` just to be sure.